# scipy.integrate.romberg -- how to pass functions with keyword arguments

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

Hopefully this is a quick, simple question, but it has got me a bit puzzled...

I have a function that takes two compulsory arguments and several keyword arguments that I want to integrate using `scipy.integrate.romberg`. I know I can pass extra arguments to `scipy.integrate.romberg` using the `args` keyword, where I can specify extra arguments as tuple, but, in the tuple, how wold I specify which function argument is the keyword argument and which are the keyword arguments?

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

def myfunc(x,y,a=1,b=2):
    if y > 1.0:
         c = (1.0+b)**a
    else:
         c = (1.0+a)**b
    return c*x

y = 2.5
a = 4.0
b = 5.0

integral = integrate.romberg(myfunc,1,10,...?) # What do I specify here so
                                               # that romberg knows that 
                                               # y = 2.5, a = 4.0, b = 5.0?
```

At first I tried defining the function inside a class, so that all the keyword arguments were set in the `__init__`, but `scipy.integrate.romberg` didn't seem to like me passing a function with `self` as the first argument. (Don't have the error message to hand right now I'm afraid)!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just doing `romberg(myfunc, 1, 10, (2.5,))`?  The way it knows which argument is which is by position.  Arguments are passed from first to last.  You mention keyword arguments but I don't see how those are germane here, since your keyword arguments have defaults and you're not passing any value to override those defaults.

Comment: @BrenBarn: That should work, but the function has four arguments, and in the code shown in the question, the OP has `a = 4.0` and `b = 5.0`, so the call should be `romberg(myfunc, 1, 10, args=(2.5, 4.0, 5.0))`.  (The explicit keyword `args` is not necessary--that's just my personal preference.)

Comment: Ah, ok, so I can just specify the arguments in the order that they appear in the function declaration? And I'm guessing that if my example code above was itself inside another function and I was using `**kwargs` to pass the keyword arguments, then I'd have to go through and extract each argument in turn to place into the tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments to the original post suggest passing the keyword arguments as positional arguments. That'll work, but will be cumbersome if there are many keyword arguments and you don't want to pass them all explicitly. A more general (and perhaps more Pythonic) way is to wrap your function using a closure like this:

```
def myfunc(x,y,a=1,b=2):
    if y > 1.0:
         c = (1.0+b)**a
    else:
         c = (1.0+a)**b
    return c*x

def mywrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    def func(x):
        return myfunc(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return func

myfunc_with_args = mywrapper(2.5, a=4.0, b=5.0)
integral = integrate.romberg(myfunc_with_args, 1, 10)
```